# Fold arbitrary number of pairs of iterators into a new iterator. Metaprogramming for a nice syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have an algorithm that takes two ranges and returns a range that iterates, computing on the fly, a special subset of elements in the first range based on the contents of the second. The special subset itself can in turn be run through this algorithm on another set. Everything works fine, but I'm banging my head against the wall trying to improve the api with variadic templates. The final clause of the main function below illustrates the goal.

```
template <class ContainerLeft, class ContainerRight>
class joincalc_const_iter : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, typename ContainerLeft::difference_type> {
public:
    joiner_const_iter& operator++(); /* does complicated stuff to find the next member of a subset in left. */

    const typename ContainerLeft::value_type& operator*() const;

    const ContainerLeft* left = nullptr;
    const ContainerRight* right = nullptr;

...
};

template <class ContainerLeft, class ContainerRight>
class JoinCalc {
public:
    typedef joincalc_const_iter<ContainerLeft, ContainerRight> const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
...
};

template<class L, class R>
JoinCalc<L, R> join(const L& left, const R& right)
{
    return JoinCalc<L, R>(left, right);
}

int main()
{
    SomeSequence a{...}, b{...};
    SomeSequenceDifferentType c{...}, d{...};

    /* Works great. */
    for (const auto& n : join(a, c))
        std::cout << n << "\n";
    for (const auto& n : join(a, b))
        std::cout << n << "\n";

    /* Works, but is a pain to write. I'm trying and failing at using variadic
     * templates to automate this. The goal is to write: join(a, b, c, d); */
    for (const auto& n : join(join(join(a, b), c), d))
        std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

I suppose one could resort to macros, but it seems like what I'm shooting for should be possible with variadic templates. I'm just not sharp enough to figure it out and I get confused by the errors. Is there a way to do it with just a template function? Or do you have to build a tuple-like thing with container semantics? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to this,

```
template<class L, class R>
JoinCalc<L, R> join(const L& left, const R& right)
{
    return JoinCalc<L, R>(left, right);
}
```

define this also,

```
//it is an overload, not specialization

template<class L, class R, class ...Rest>
auto join(const L& left, const R& right, Rest const & ... rest) 
                    -> decltype(join(JoinCalc<L, R>(left, right), rest...))
{
    return join(JoinCalc<L, R>(left, right), rest...);
}
```

Note the trailing-return-type.

**How does it work?**

If there are more than 2 arguments, the second overload will be invoked, else the first overload will be invoked.

By the way, I would suggest you to accept the arguments as universal references, and use `std::forward` to forward the arguments to the constructor and other overload.

Comment: Ahh, I kept trying to do it with only template specialization. Much thanks.